# How to use poll_message_set()?

Tags: python

How to use `poll_message_set()` in the operator?

API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.poll_message_set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used in the poll() method of an Operator just before returning False to set a message explaining why the operator can't be called.

Here's an example from the builtin `pose_library` addon in Blender 3.5.1 (when in doubt, always grep the default addons for usage examples!)

```
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context: Context) -> bool:
        action = context.object and context.object.animation_data and context.object.animation_data.action
        if not action:
            cls.poll_message_set("Active object has no Action")
            return False
        if not action.pose_markers:
            cls.poll_message_set(tip_("Action %r is not a legacy pose library") % action.name)
            return False
        return True
```